# Get all none available query oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with these columns code, licenseno, licensetype, dateeffective, expirydate

and for each code there are at least 4 different licensetypes. I want to show first the unavailable lines where the expirydate of at least one of the licensetypes is passed the present date. The hard part is that for each licensetype i can renew its expirydate. Here is an example table with values:

```
2           A   4   1-Jan-2014  1-Jan-2015
2           A   4   1-Jan-2013  1-Jan-2014
2           A   3   1-Jan-2014  1-Jan-2015 
2           A   2   1-Jan-2013  9-Jun-2014 
2           A   1   1-Jan-2013  10-May-2014
3           B   4   1-Jan-2013  9-Oct-2014 
3           B   4   13-Jun-2013 6-Jan-2014 
3           B   2   6-Jan-2014  3-Mar-2014 
3           B   2   10-Feb-2014 5-Mar-2014 
13          C   2   1-Jan-2014  1-Jan-2015 
13          C   1   1-Jan-2013  1-Jan-2014 
3000115     D   1   1-Jan-2014  1-Jan-2015 
3000217     E   3   1-Jan-2012  1-Jan-2013 
3000222     F   2   1-Jan-2014  1-Jan-2015 
3000222     F   4   1-Jan-2014  1-Jan-2015
3000223     G   2   1-Jan-2011  1-Jan-2012
```

So for example the one with code '2' on licenseno '4' it has expired on '1-Jan-2014' but renewed until '1-Jan-2015'. So the whole code '2' will not have any field that is considered unavailable since all last dates on each licensetype for each code has not passed.

So i want all the codes that are unavailable. If any of the licensetypes is expired then the whole code will be considered unavailable.

I have written this for start but it works only if i know and pass manually the code which is not what i need:

```
select distinct  code
            from licenserevisions 
            where expirydate<sysdate and code='3' and (select count(code) from licenserevisions where expirydate>sysdate and code='3')=0
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
code
3
13
3000217
3000223
```

Any idea people?

Comment: Can you put the expected output as well?

Comment: ive added an expected output and changed the values i gave you m8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking something like this

```
WITH table_name( code, licenseno, licensetype, dateeffective, expirydate) AS (
SELECT 2, 'A', 4, '1-Jan-2014', '1-Jan-2015' from dual union all
SELECT 2, 'A', 4, '1-Jan-2013', '1-Jan-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 2, 'A', 3, '1-Jan-2014', '1-Jan-2015' from dual union all
SELECT 2, 'A', 2, '1-Jan-2013', '9-Jun-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 2, 'A', 1, '1-Jan-2013', '10-May-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 3, 'B', 4, '1-Jan-2013', '9-Oct-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 3, 'B', 4, '13-Jun-2013', '6-Jan-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 3, 'B', 2, '6-Jan-2014', '3-Mar-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 3, 'B', 2, '10-Feb-2014', '5-Mar-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 13, 'C', 2, '1-Jan-2014', '1-Jan-2015' from dual union all
SELECT 13, 'C', 1, '1-Jan-2013', '1-Jan-2014' from dual union all
SELECT 3000115, 'D', 1, '1-Jan-2014', '1-Jan-2015' from dual union all
SELECT 3000217, 'E', 3, '1-Jan-2012', '1-Jan-2013' from dual union all
SELECT 3000222, 'F', 2, '1-Jan-2014', '1-Jan-2015' from dual union all
SELECT 3000222, 'F', 4, '1-Jan-2014', '1-Jan-2015' from dual union all
SELECT 3000223, 'G', 2, '1-Jan-2011', '1-Jan-2012' from dual ),
expired AS (SELECT * 
              FROM table_name
             WHERE expirydate < SYSDATE),
not_expired AS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table_name
                 WHERE expirydate >= SYSDATE)
SELECT DISTINCT e.code 
  FROM expired e
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 'x' 
                     FROM not_expired b 
                    WHERE b.code = e.code
                      AND b.licensetype = e.licensetype)
```

output

```
|    CODE |
|---------|
|      13 |
| 3000217 |
| 3000223 |
|       3 |
```

And thus your final query is

```
WITH expired AS (SELECT * 
                   FROM table_name
                  WHERE expirydate < SYSDATE),
not_expired AS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table_name
                 WHERE expirydate >= SYSDATE)
SELECT DISTINCT e.code 
  FROM expired e
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 'x' 
                     FROM not_expired b 
                    WHERE b.code = e.code
                      AND b.licensetype = e.licensetype)
```